# Fantasy book that I read some years back involving a city of elves, giant hornets, and a desert crossing

Tags: story-identification, books

The only thing I can remember is that the main character was invited to a city of elves by his elf friend. The elf friend might have been the prince of elves or some sort of nobility. I also remember there were giant hornets in the book as well. There was a stretch in the book where the main character and his group had to cross a desert.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! When abouts did you read this?

Comment: I don't know maybe around 3 - 5 years ago or so.

Comment: I found the book, it is called spellscribed and its a series with five books in in should anyone be interested in in reading the series.

Comment: This is the link to the series [link](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B074CGKGMB?binding=kindle_edition&searchxofy=true&ref_=dbs_s_aps_series_rwt_tkin&qid=1710955441&sr=8-3)

Comment: Please would you consider creating a formal answer so you can accept it? Please see [answer] for more information and some helpful tips